# Byte array ClassCastException when deleting in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink in my Java EE project. My project is deployed using Glassfish 6.2.3. I am using UUIDs as primary keys in my SQL relations. When trying to delete an entity, I get a ClassCastException which reads that the byte array cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable class.

Following is the detailed stack trace:

```
[2022-01-30T16:44:29.422+0530] [glassfish 6.2] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/shin/Documents/glassfish6/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/WebService-0.0.1/WEB-INF/classes/_Resource_details] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1643541269422] [levelValue: 900] [[
  
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable ([B and java.lang.Comparable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1569)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.addEntryToEmptyMap(TreeMap.java:776)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:785)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.sort(CommitManager.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1510)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:138)
    at com.example.RESTService.Resources.RolesResource.deleteRole(RolesResource.java:231)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:34)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]
```

This is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Role.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Role r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Role.findByName", query = "SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Role.findByCreatedAt", query = "SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.createdAt = :createdAt"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Role.findByIsActive", query = "SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.isActive = :isActive")})
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "id")
    private byte[] id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private byte[] createdBy;
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Character isActive;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(byte[] id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Role(byte[] id, String name, byte[] createdBy) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public byte[] getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(byte[] id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[] getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(byte[] createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Character getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Character isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Role)) {
            return false;
        }
        Role other = (Role) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.example.RESTService.Role[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

This is the call to the delete the role:

```
public void deleteRole(String roleName) {
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        try {
            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            TypedQuery<Role> outletTypedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Role.findByName", Role.class);
            outletTypedQuery.setParameter("name", roleName);
            Role outletEntity = outletTypedQuery.getSingleResult();
            entityManager.remove(outletEntity);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
}
```

I am wondering if what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: A byte[] as a primary key ? How strange.

Comment: The id in role relation in the DB is of type binary(16). This is how I initialize the id before inserting it:
```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
id = bb.array();
```

If I am using UUIDs as my primary key, should I be using a different datatype?

Comment: according to the documentation 

"The field or property to which the Id annotation is applied should be
one of the following types: any Java primitive type; any primitive
wrapper type; String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date;
java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInteger."

Comment: How will you filter and compare (and index) the lob column in the database? UUID usage I've seen on projects generally convert it to a string format, letting it be human readable and comparable, both in the database and in the data representations. Byte[] isn't.

Comment: Now that I think about indexing, I realize that using UUIDs will not have a natural sorting in the DB. I read this article, https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439. The author suggests not to use UUIDs as primary keys, and warns of using strings to represent UUIDs. My intuition of using UUIDs as primary keys was to save an extra call to DB to fetch a value for primary key. I am in a early stage of development. Reading the articles on the web has got me thinking if UUIDs is in itself a good choice for primary keys.

Comment: If you want natural sorting, it is common to add a creation date. Using Identifiers for natural sorting puts certain requirements on assigning them sequentially, which can hinder performance in highly concurrent apps.